# Create pandas date column based one and dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, datetime

I have two columns (dataframe) :

| Date | Periode |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-01-03 | YEARS |
| 2019-05-05 | MONTHS |

And one dict with periode to correspond days :

```
dict_range={"YEARS" : 20.0 , "MONTHS" : 3.0}
```

I would like to create a new column which increment date period dict to date like this :

| Date | Periode | Range_plus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-03 | YEARS | 2019-01-23 |
| 2019-05-05 | MONTHS | 2019-05-08 |

I notice the date column type is "DateTime" and dict key value is "Float".

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) your values from the dictionary, then convert [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) (with `unit='D'` for days) and add to the date (optionally ensuring it's a date with [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)):

```
df['Range_plus'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
                      .add(pd.to_timedelta(df['Periode'].map(dict_range),
                                           unit='D'))
                   )
```

If you already know `Date` is a `datetime` dtype:

```
df['Range_plus'] = (df['Date']
                    .add(pd.to_timedelta(df['Periode'].map(dict_range),
                                         unit='D'))
                   )
```

Output:

```
         Date Periode Range_plus
0  2019-01-03   YEARS 2019-01-23
1  2019-05-05  MONTHS 2019-05-08
```